# TSP on a non-complete graph

Tags: linear-programming, modeling

I have a non-complete graph $G$ with $V$ vertices and a set $D \subset V$ that needs to be traveled by a vehicle and then return to source at last.

Binary variables $b_{i,j}$ represent if the edge $(i,j)$ is taken or not. $G_{i,j}$ represent the distance between node $i$ and node $j$.

$$\min \sum_{i,j\in V}b_{i,j} \cdot G_{i,j}$$

Below 2 constraints eliminate loops:

$$ \sum_{j\in V}b_{i,j}  \leq 1$$

$$ \sum_{j\in V}b_{j,i} \leq 1$$

The following constraint ensures that there are only one incoming and one outgoing edges for each node.

$$\sum_{j\in V}b_{j,i} - \sum_{j\in V}b_{i,j} = 0 \ \ \ \forall j \in V$$

Below constraint ensures that all the nodes in $D$ must be visited.

$$\sum_{j\in V}b_{j,i} = 1 \ \ \ \forall i \in D$$

MTZ. constraint:  $\forall (i,j) \in V$ and $(i,j) \neq D_0$, i.e., starting node.

$$ U_i - U_j + |V| \cdot b_{i,j} \leq |V| - 1$$

The problem with this model is, it is slow, I am looking for some ways to make it faster.

The reason I am not able to apply Danzig-Fulkerson-Johnson formulation is that the size of $V = 72$ so creating all subset is not possible. Another way of doing it is to create a complete graph for $D$ and then apply Danzig-Fulkerson-Johnson but I need to know the nodes that are used to reach nodes in set $D$ that's why I can't create complete graph also there are other constraints that can change the route to reach nodes in set $D$.

I have also tried Desrochers-Laporte formulation but there is no significant difference.

**My question is:**

Is there any way to use Danzig-Fulkerson-Johnson formulation in this or some other way to solve the problem faster.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are solving a kind of a shortest path problem so you could add a generalized version of the subtour elimination constraints as
$$ \sum_{(i,j) \in \delta^+(S)} b_{ij} \geq \sum_{(k,j) \in \delta^+(k)} b_{kj}, \; \forall k \in S, \forall S \subseteq V, |S| \geq 2  $$
where $\delta^+$ represents the outgoing edges of a set of nodes. Alternatively as
$$  \sum_{(i,j) \in E(S)} b_{ij} \leq \sum_{i \in S\setminus (k)} \sum_{(i,j) \in \delta^+(i)} b_{ij}, \; \forall k \in S,\forall S \subseteq V, |S| \geq 2 $$
with $E(S)$ being the edges within the node set $S$.

Have a look at the paper [A branch-and-cut algorithm for the capacitated profitable tour problem](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S157252861400036X) by Jepsen et al. for more cuts and separation details. It is for the undirected case but can be modified for the directed case.

Comment: I have $|V| = 600$ and $|D| = 20$(destination) then $\forall S \subset V$, will it be possible to compute all subset?

Comment: You can find the most violating subtour by solving a minimum (s,t)-cut for each node $s \in V\setminus(t)$ for a $t \in D$. Edge weights are the fractional values of the edge variables. I think enumeration of all subsets would take too long and you would create a massive amount of non-binding constraints.

Comment: OK, I have a set `D = [2,3,5,4,2]` now after performing mincut on `(2,3), (2,5) ..., (3,5), (3,4) ...`, I get a set of mincut edges `E = [(6,9), (8,10), ...]`. Now I am confused what to do next.

Comment: From the endpoints of the mincut edges you get $S$ and $V \setminus S$. Just saw that Wolsey have an example at p. 155 in "Integer Programming"

Comment: So what I have understood till now is that from the edges of mincut I should pick their endpoints and create a set $S$ and apply DFJ formulation but take only those subsets that contain one of the nodes from set $S$.OR I can just add constraints enforcing that some of the edges from the mincut edge set needs to be taken. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: I am not entirely sure I understand what you propose. But I think your first approach.

Comment: My graph is like a 2D grid so for $|V| = 600$ all subset generation after taking care of mincut set is still too large to generate. Do you know any link where someone has implemented this in any language?

Comment: In a cutting plane algorithm you would need to solve the mincut once for each node with non-zero value for each iteration. From each of these cuts you can derive a $S$ and the $k$ and if the corresponding constraint is violated then add it. I suggest to find a graph library in your preferred language to solve the mincut problem. Note, that implementing this with a solver you would need to use callbacks to add the cuts.